# set parametermap in munit

Tags: mule, munit

am facing difficult to set ParameterMap in munit.  when i set http.uri.params in munit  and its working fine normally. but unable to access its values though ParameterMap. please refer the following the MUnit code(which is working fine when i access #[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.serviceName] ) and Java Code

```
<munit:inbound-property key="http.uri.params" value="#[['serviceName': 'services','loanNumber':'1111']]"/>
```

this is how i am accessing http.uri.params In My code

```
ParameterMap pMap = eventContext.getMessage().getInboundProperty("http.uri.params");
```

so when i run munit ,above line throws exception (java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.mule.module.http.internal.ParameterMap)

is there any way set parametermap in munit without changing my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot change your code to not depend on ParameterMap. Then you could try creating the ParameterMap instance in your Munit code. It has an overlaoded constructor that allows passing a map to it:

```
<munit:inbound-property key="http.uri.params" value="#[new org.mule.module.http.internal.ParameterMap((['serviceName': 'services','loanNumber':'1111']))]"/>
```

Java doc: https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.7.0/apidocs/org/mule/module/http/internal/ParameterMap.html

Comment: thanks bro but when i try that, it throws "Execution of the expression "message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.serviceName" failed." is there any other way to do that?

Comment: I thought that may happen. The best way is to refactor your class not to rely on mule internals.

Comment: @ rayan carter. i found the solution for this problem. anyway thanks for you help. right now i am facing new problem. thats is  [org.mule.munit.remote.CoverageManager]Coverage report calculation failed. do you knw how to solve this problem?